# How to download Oracle 11g database standard edition (not enterprise edition)

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, rdbms

I want to use Oracle 11g database standard edition   but on oracle home site I got enterprise edition. please help me to download 11g database standard edition for windows 10 64bit

Comment: It's the same download. [Get it from here](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/112010-win64soft.html). One of the steps in running `setup.exe` includes choosing whether to install Standard or Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Please be aware that Oracle 11g is out of support AND is not certified for Windows 10.

Comment: yaa I got it ..thanks